# How to call ajax method after a control loads completely in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am using ASP.NET MVC. 
There is a ajax call to populate a value in an input box based on the selected  dropdownlist value in the same view on loading of the screen. It is working when i am calling this in dropdownlist change.

Issue : I am not able to get the dropdownlist selected value in the ajax call on page load.

Is there any way to trigger the ajax call only after the dropdownlist loading.

Thanks in Advance.
Sandy

Comment: you can trigger your ajax call in success event of ajax call that loads dropdownlist

Comment: This is a Kendo dorpdownlist..

Comment: there is dataSource.requestEnd event http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-requestEnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it on the [document ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) event.

```
$(function(){

  var val=$("#YourDropdownId").val();
  // now make the ajax call

});
```

The code inside document `ready` will be executed when the DOM is fully loaded.

But if you are loading the dropdown using ajax, you can execute your custom ajax call in the `done` event after you populate the dropdown options.

```
$(function(){

   $.ajax({
     url: "SomeServerEndpointReturningJsonData"

   }).done(function(response) {
      //loop through the response and load the data
      var items="";
      $.each(response,function(index,item){
         items+="<option value="+item.Id+">"+item.Name+"</option>";
      });
      $("#YourDropDownId").append(items);

      var val=$("#YourDropdownId").val();      
      //Make your second ajax call.
  });


});
```

Assuming your server endpoint returns json data like

```
[{Id:1,Name:"A"},{Id:2,Name:"B"}]
```